# Angular router doesn't go to Component directly?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have created a data table (see Image 1) with one column that has a button inside of it. This button changes the application's route and navigates to a detail component(see code below & URL).

```
goToDetailOfWearable(wearable: ResultWearable) {
console.log(wearable);
this.resultService.sendResultWearableToService(wearable).then(
  () => {
    this.languageService.languageSelectAvailable.next(true);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('Home/ProcessCategory/Processes/Activities/Result/Details').then(
      (x) => console.log(x)
    );
  }
);
```

}

However this button doens't route, just clears the data table (see Image 2). But if I navigate back and directly forward with the browser (so go back to the data table, and forward to the detail component with the browser). It now correctly routes to the correct route (see Image 3).

[Datatable Component, with button in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS9no.jpg)

[Result of button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31K17.jpg)

[Correct route, accessed by navigating back and forth with the browser(red square)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emkRY.jpg)

[Updated the button method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRyjf.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Also, the `navigateByUrl` method return a `Promise<boolean>`, and that boolean indicates whether Angular thinks the navigation was successful, can you please add `.then(console.log)`  to your `navigateByUrl` method so we can understand whether the navigation from that page was successful.

Comment: I have no console and the promise returns true when I print it. So is the router working??? then why does the route not change???. Added 4th image

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you put `<base href="/">` in the `index.html` ? The route path look very long and detailed.. It seems that you don't navigating to _next_ component but navigating from root -> to component..

Comment: Yes i have included <base href="/"> in my index.html file.