# Angular router doesn't render Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, lifecycle

I have created a data table (see Image 1) with one column that has a button inside of it. This button changes the application's route and navigates to a detail component(see code below & URL).

```
goToDetailOfWearable(wearable: ResultWearable) {
console.log(wearable);
this.resultService.sendResultWearableToService(wearable).then(
  () => {
    this.languageService.languageSelectAvailable.next(true);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('Home/ProcessCategory/Processes/Activities/Result/Details').then(
      (x) => console.log(x)
    );
  }
);}
```

However this button doens't route, just clears the data table (see Image 2). But if I navigate back and directly forward with the browser (so go back to the data table, and forward to the detail component with the browser). It now correctly routes to the correct route (see Image 3). But the router.nabigateByUrl method returns true in the console (see Image 4), so why doenst it render it directly?

[Datatable, button to route in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EEJs.jpg)

[Unwanted result after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXAOr.jpg)

[Correct route, accessed by navigating back and forth with the browser(red square)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNQVb.jpg)

[The navigatebyUrl, however return true???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj4jT.jpg)

Comment: Do not use nested callbacks like that. Your code is hard to read and maintain. Use the [syntactic sugar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: **[You already posted your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186768/angular-router-doesnt-go-to-component-directly)**. If no one answered it, you don't need to post it again to make them answer. I'm flagging your question.